# iPhone: is it possible to enable/disable phone features programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to **lock / unlock some features** of iPhone such as send/receive text message, make the phone silent for incoming call etc while using my application.

**Is it possible?** If possible, How?

Comment: http://iphonepackers.info/ in this link you may get some help. For detail answer search google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not an Apple-approved way of controlling this. However, you can "prevent" your phone from locking when your app is running. `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES` should do it.